# If I have a 1x1 card and then I want to install а 2x2 card. Do I have to change antennas, too?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

If I have a 1x1 card and then I want to install а 2x2 card. Do I have to change antennas, too or I just install a new 2x2 card and that is it?

Comment: Could you add some additional detail on the exact hardware?

Comment: A wireless card must be selected to connect to a wireless network.
    ThinkPad b/g/n Wireless & Bluetooth 4.0 (1x1 BGN & BT 4.0)
   
    Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230 & Bluetooth 4.0 (2x2 BGN & BT4) The question is, if I already have this 1x1 card, but I want to install a 2x2 card, do I have to deal with antennas or I just connect them
   
    ThinkPad a/b/g/n Wireless & Bluetooth 4.0 (2x2 ABGN & BT 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

Some Thinkpads had the antenna for BlueTooth installed and the cable is not connected so simply install and connect the WiFi and BT antenna and youa re good.

However, many Thinkpads do not have the antenna and cable installed.  My T61 and others I have worked on required the screen bezel be removed to install the hardware.

The exact model of the laptop might get a definitive answer.